# Prove $|A + B| ≥ |A| + |B| - 1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, additive-combinatorics

Let A and B be two non-empty sets of real numbers. Define A + B to be the set
$$A+B = \{ a + b : a ∈ A, b ∈ B\}$$
For instance, if $A =\{1,3,4\}$ and $B = \{1,3\}$, then $A + B =\{2,4,5,6,7\}$. show that in any case, we have 
$$|A + B| ≥ |A| + |B| - 1$$

Comment: can you please explain it in a simpler way, i don't quiet understand how you solve it. but regardless, thanks for your answer. @MoonLightSyzygy

Comment: Let $M=\max(A)$ and $n=\min(B)$. The number of elements of $\{M\}+B$ is $|B|$. Note that $\{M\}+B\subset A+B$. Similarly, $A+\{n\}$ has $|A|$ elements and $A+\{n\}\subset A+B$. If $M+b=a+n$, for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then we must have $M=a$ and $b=n$. Therefore, $(\{M\}+B)\cap(A+\{n\})=\{M+n\}$. So, $|A+B|\geq |\{M\}+B|+|A+\{n\}|-1=|B|+|A|-1$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy.   It was not given that A and B have a maximum or a minimum.

Comment: @WilliamElliot So what? The case where one of them doesn't is trivial.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy can i ask how can {M} + B is |B| ?

Comment: @bryan That is because you are just adding the same number $M$ to each element of $B$. Note that any two sums $M+b_1$ and $M+b_2$ for $b_1,b_2\in B$ are equal only when $b_1=b_2$. So, you get different elements in $\{M\}+B$ for each element of $B$ that you use.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy oh i see now, thanks! you are such a lifesaver

Comment: Should make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to think about this is via orderings. In particular, you can put a partial order on the cartesian product $A\times B$ by saying $(a,b) \geq (a',b')$ if $a \geq a'$ and $b\geq b'$. Clearly, if $(a,b) > (a',b')$ then $a+b > a'+b'$. However, this product can be visualized as a grid with dimensions of $|A|$ by $|B|$; we can easily find ascending chains of length $|A|+|B|-1$ - whose sums must all be distinct because they are increasing.

To be really explicit, this argument tells us that if we write $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_{|A|}\}$ and $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_{|B|}\}$ in increasing order, we have that $A+B$ contains an increasing sequence
\begin{align*}a_1&+b_1\\
a_2&+b_1\\
a_3&+b_1\\
&\,\vdots\\
a_{|A|-1}&+b_1\\
a_{|A|}&+b_1\\
a_{|A|}&+b_2\\
a_{|A|}&+b_3\\
&\,\vdots\\
a_{|A|}&+b_{|B|-1}\\
a_{|A|}&+b_{|B|}
\end{align*}
As this list is increasing from top to bottom, the elements in it must be distinct. There are $|A|+|B|-1$ elements in this list.

It is not too hard to extend this argument to find out that $|A+B| = |A|+|B|-1$ exactly if $A$ and $B$ are both arithmetic progressions of the same step size.